# How to handle a database when multiple docker instances of DB(MySQL, MongoDB) is using same table from same DB?

Tags: database

Suppose I am running lets say 50 replica of Kubernetes Pod of service X. Each Pod of service X has one instance of of MySQL. Service X is using X-DB, hence all Pods having total 50 MySQL instances(docker containers) and each is using same DB, X-DB.

**Here is actual problem,**

Lets say there one table 'Inventory' in X-DB is being accessed by service X, each instance of service is taking to its own MySQL instance inside its Pod. This MySQL is creating records in 'Inventory' table. Hence all MySQL instance in 50 Pods are creating records in 50 'Inventory' tables.

My question is how to merge all 50 'Inventory' tables into once so that each service X can get full 'Inventory' table.

Or suggest the solution for this.

Comment: see mysql replication. also you don't need to create 50 mysql instances. create 2/3 seperately and add replication to them.